# How do I get the last character with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string I am trying to get the last character with jquery.  How would I do that?

```
var stringTemp = "fieldNameWithIndex_1";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stringTemp.charAt(stringTemp.length-1);
```

or

```
stringTemp.slice(-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.split()`:

```
 stringTemp.split('_')[1]
```